# search for a record in hibernate if exist then link with table employee else create and then link

Tags: java, mysql, swing, hibernate

code for employee.java

```
package Data;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {


private int empid;
private String empName;
private String empEmailAddress;
private boolean isActive;
    private String empAddress;
    private String empphone;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Department> deptobj;= new ArrayList<Department>();

    private  String emprole;
    private Integer salary;


    public void setdeptobj(List<Department> deptobj) {
    this.deptobj; = deptobj;
}
public List<Department> getdeptobj() {
    return deptobj;;
}

public void setempEmailAddress(String empEmailAddress) {
    this.empEmailAddress = empEmailAddress;
}
public String getempEmailAddress() {
    return empEmailAddress;
}
    public boolean getisActive() {
    return isActive;
}
public void setisActive(boolean isActive) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
}
    public String getempAddress() {
    return empAddress;
}
public void setempAddress(String empAddress) {
    this.empAddress = empAddress;
}
public String getempphone() {
    return empphone;
}
public void setempphone(String empphone) {
    this.empphone = empphone;
}


public String getemprole() {
    return emprole;
}
public void setemprole(String emprole) {
    this.emprole = emprole;
}

    public int getsalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setsalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

@Id
public int getEmpid() {
    return empid;
}
public void setEmpid(int empid) {
    this.empid = empid;
}
public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}
public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}

}
```

code for Department.java

```
package Data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;


@Entity
public class Department {
private String dept;

@ManyToOne
private Employee employee;
@Id
private int deptid;

public String getdept() {
    return dept;
}
public void setdept(String dept) {
    this.dept = dept;
}

    public int getdeptid() {
    return deptid;
}
public void setdeptid(int deptid) {
    this.deptid = deptid;
}

   private Employee getemployee(){
       return employee;
   }

   private void setemployee(Employee employee){
       this.employee = employee;
   }

}
```

code for middle layer

```
package service;

import Data.*;
import static com.mchange.v2.log.MLog.config;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class ServiceLayer {
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession() ;


public void add(Employee emp){


    session.beginTransaction();
            System.out.println("hello");
            session.save(emp);
            System.out.println("hello");
            session.getTransaction().commit();

}

public void delete(int empid){


    session.beginTransaction();

            Employee emp = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, empid);
            session.delete(emp);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

}

public void update(Employee emp){

    session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(emp);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
}

public void read(){

    session.beginTransaction();
            String hql = "select * from Employee;";
            session.createSQLQuery(hql);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

 }

 public Department check(String dept){
   session.beginTransaction();

    SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("from Department d where d.dept=:deptname");
    q.setParameter("deptname", dept);
    Department d = (Department) q.uniqueResult();

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return d;
}
 public Department getDept(Department list){

   session.beginTransaction();
  Department deptobj= (Department) session.get(Department.class, (Serializable) list.getdeptid());
   session.getTransaction().commit();
   return deptobj;
}

public void addDept(Department dep){
   session.beginTransaction();
   session.save(dep);

   session.getTransaction().commit();
}

}
```

code for mainservice layer

```
package mainService;

import Data.*;
import static java.sql.Types.NULL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import service.ServiceLayer;


public class Logic {
private int empid;
private String empName;
ServiceLayer sl = new ServiceLayer();
private String empPassword;
private String empEmailAddress;
private boolean isPermanent;
private Calendar empJoinDate;



public void add(String empName,String empEmailAddress,String empAddress,String empphone,String dept,String emprole,Integer salary,boolean active){
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setEmpName(empName);
    emp.setempAddress(empAddress);
    emp.setempEmailAddress(empEmailAddress);
    emp.setempphone(empphone);

    emp.setemprole(emprole);
    emp.setsalary(salary);
    emp.setisActive(active);
    Department dep = null;

   Department list = sl.check(dept);
    if(list.getdeptid()==NULL){
      dep = addDept(dept);
    }
    else{
    dep = sl.getDept(list);
    }

    emp.getdeptobj().add((Department) dep);
    sl.add(emp);
}

private Department addDept(String dept) {
    Department dep = new Department();
    dep.setdept(dept);
    sl.addDept(dep);
    Department list = sl.check(dept);
    dep = (Department) sl.getDept(list);
    return dep;

}

}
```

Service layer gets the values from form created in swing then it passes the data to `ServiceLayer.java` file which creates session and sets the value to create a record and then save that record THE problem is I want to check if department already exists, then link with that for that search will be based on department name given by user if department does not exixt then first create new department and then link with employee.

I am not able to get where the problem is because I haven't used hibernate before... so please help me. And on running the file I am getting the ERROR of

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.MappingException: 
     Could not determine type for: java.util.List, for columns:
     [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(deptobj)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you put JPA annotations on getters, consistently, or you put them on fields, consistently. Mixing both in a single class makes Hibernate ignore all the ones that aren't placed on the same location as the `@Id` annotation.

Also, your mapping is weird: a department has a single employee, which also belongs to other departments? Is this a mapping for a single-person company doing everything? You probably want the association in the other direction: a department has many employees, and each employee belongs to one department.

Comment: ok sorry for that in consistency.. i followed this http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-one-to-many-and-many-to-one-mapping-between-two-database-tables-using-hibernate/28353 so you mean i have to use @ManyToOne
private Department deptid; in employee.java...?

Comment: Bad choice. Several errors, awful naming choices. How about reading the official documentation? What I mean is exactly what I said: all the annotations should be on fields, not on getters. Or all the annotations should be on getters, not fields.  You must not havesome on getters and some on fields. The part on OneToMany is not technical, but functional: what do you want to represent? Several employees belonging to one department, or several departments each containing a single employee?

Comment: please guide me from where i can learn this onetomany and other hibernate concepts and please tell me how can i check whether record exist in table and if exist how to link it... its urgent

Comment: yes i want to represent several employee exist in one department

Comment: So, **many** employees to **one** department. So Employee should have a field of type Department, annotated with ManyToOne. And Department should have a field of type Set<Employee>, annotated with OneToMany. I already guided you: read the **official** Hibernate documentation.